# Confirm if it was inserted into MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a registration form in PhP submitting various entries into a MySQL database.

The code is as:

```
if($conn)
    {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Participants
       (ID,
        title, 
        surname,
        name,
        organization1,
        organization2,
        address1,
        address2,
        country,
        email,
        phone,
        type_reg,
        abstract,
        bm1,
        bm2,
        bm3,
        bm4                 )

        VALUES         
       ('$auth_id',
        '$auth_title', 
        '$auth_sname',
        '$auth_name',
        '$auth_org_line1',
        '$auth_org_line2',
        '$auth_add_line1',
        '$auth_add_line2',
        '$auth_country',
        '$auth_email',
        '$auth_phonen',
        '$reg_type',
        '$new_file_name',
        '$bm1',
        '$bm2',
        '$bm3',
        '$bm4'          )";


    mysql_query($sql);
    if( mysql_errno() !== 1062) {
        print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
        print 'alert("Your pre-registration has been submitted successfully. You will receive a confirmation e-mail soon.")';
        print '</script>';
        print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
        print 'parent.location.href = "Success.html"';
        print '</script>';
mysql_close($conn);
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'Data base error. Try later.';
    }
```

Because I am sending confirmation e-mails with cc to me, I am aware of the people registering and when I check the database I find that some of them are not being inserted into the database.

What I'm looking for is for a way to only validate the registration IF the entries were inserted into the MySQL table.

Is there a simple way?

Should I verify if the query was successful? How?

Should I look for the ID on the table and verify if it exists? How? (the entry ID is set as unique)

Comment: MySQL_Query functions are deprecated, you should use PDO instead

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `mysql_affected_rows()` will return the number of rows affected by your query. If zero, it was not inserted. If >= 1, it was.

So:

`if ( mysql_affected_rows() >= 1 ){ /* inserted! now do something... */ }`

If you are using an auto-incrementing column for row ID, you can use `mysql_insert_id()` as well:

`if ( mysql_insert_id() > 0 ) { /* inserted! now do something... */ }`